# Front-end Registration Form just refreshes with no error displayed and user not created

Tags: registration

I am using the registration form from the docs here - https://craftcms.com/docs/templating/user-registration-form - in the front end of my site. Unfortunately, when I click on "Register" the page just refreshes and no errors are displayed, and the user is not created.

I have checked the following:

- "Allow Public Registration?" is checked in the CP.
- I made sure that the Snaptcha plugin was disabled (just in case).

Any ideas on what I should look for?

Thanks!

```
<form method="post" action="" accept-charset="UTF-8">
<input type="hidden" name="action" value="users/saveUser">
<input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="/success/">

{% macro errorList(errors) %}
    {% if errors %}
        <ul class="errors">
            {% for error in errors %}
                <li>{{ error }}</li>
            {% endfor %}
        </ul>
    {% endif %}
{% endmacro %}

{% from _self import errorList %}

<label for="username">Username</label>
<input id="username" type="text" name="username"
    {%- if account is defined %} value="{{ account.username }}"{% endif -%}>

{% if account is defined %}
    {{ errorList(account.getErrors('username')) }}
{% endif %}

<label for="email">Email</label>
<input id="email" type="text" name="email"
    {%- if account is defined %} value="{{ account.email }}"{% endif %}>

{% if account is defined %}
    {{ errorList(account.getErrors('email')) }}
{% endif %}

<label for="password">Password</label>
<input id="password" type="password" name="password">

{% if account is defined %}
    {{ errorList(account.getErrors('password')) }}
{% endif %}

  <div class="divider"></div>


<input type="submit" value="Register" class="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Can you check through your craft/storage/runtime/logs files for any [error] or [warning] logs that might be related?

Comment: Thanks @BradBell! Yes - I checked that too, although I didn't see anything that looked like a login error. Just an error about status: `FROM `craft_tasks`
WHERE (level = 0) AND (status = :status). Bound with :status='error')
2014/09/02 21:50:09 [profile] [system.db.CDbCommand.query] end:system.db.CDbCommand.query(SELECT count(`id`)` - Could that be related?

Comment: That shouldn't matter. Can you share your template code in the original question?

Comment: Np! Added the code @BradBell

Comment: Hrm... maybe you've got some required fields on your User field layout that the front-end form isn't taking into account?

Comment: I thought so too, although I checked and don't have those required. They also still display the "Make Required" option in Field Layout. Do you think it is a permissions issue? Is there a folder I should check permissions for under App? I am on Firehost and have permissions of 755 on the app folders now.

Comment: I highly doubt it's permissions related, but I am kind of stumped.  If no one else can offer any ideas, hit us up at support@buildwithcraft.com with your templates and a database back and we can look into it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved the mystery. :) The issue was that even though my user fields were not required, there was a numeric 'year' field which had min and max values set, and this was throwing it off (and I had removed that field during my last round of testing to keep things simple). Removing those required min and max values allowed the form to be submitted. Thanks for the help Brad!

Comment: Ahh... nice catch!